# Ignore cells that aren't numbers without using IsNumber

Tags: google-sheets, filter, sum, google-sheets-formula, sumproduct

The formula in cell F3 is this

```
=SUMPRODUCT($A$4:$A$2000, F4:F2000,--($A$4:$A$2000>=0*F4:F2000>=0))
```

It multiplies Col A with Col F (and then col G, H, etc) and gives the result in row 3.

Some cells contain 'N/A' or 'tr'. I hoped that last `>=0` condition would somehow just ignore them but alas.  I'm hoping there is a simple of way of saying: **ignore everything that isn't a number**. I tried `if(isnumber)` but I was putting it everywhere because I didn't know exactly where it should go in this case, and all those if then conditions were getting so long!

Is there a simpler way?  Or if I do have to use `iserror` (or `if(ISNA)`) and/or `if(isnumber)`, can someone give me clue as to where they should go and if there is a way to avoid the if condition?

[Here's the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cDw0gJsOqWBazEakacAGtrjisqQJtAbERNv8y9Ifvpk/edit?usp=sharing) if the image doesn't do the trick.
[image: Image of the sheet]

Comment: Just in case anyone needs a similar formula for use in Excel, SUMPRODUCT is it. I added the if isna condition to overlook #N/As in the columns.
=SUMPRODUCT($A$4:$A$500, IF(ISNA(F$4:F$500),0,F$4:F$500))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use in F3 and drag to the right:

```
=INDEX(SUM(IFERROR($A4:$A*F4:F)))
```

[image]

or delete F3:I3 and use this only in F3:

```
=INDEX(TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR($A4:$A*F4:I, 0)), SEQUENCE(ROWS(A4:A), 1, 1, 0))))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm ready to start a new thread pointing to this one but I figured I'd ask here first just in case it's something really small and silly that I'm missing: I have to do the same thing in Excel, but none of the answers here work in Excel - I get 0 or "I entered too few arguments". Asking here first in case Excel has a quirk I don't know about.

Comment: @lise that's a common misconception. in most cases, advanced formulae rarely work in other applications. that been said, I am not able to help you out with this one due to a lack of Excel expertise

Answer (score 1):

In F3 try

```
=SUMPRODUCT($A$4:$A$2000, $A$4:$A$2000>=0, isnumber(F$4:F$2000), F$4:F$2000)
```

or

```
=SUM(FILTER($A$4:$A$2000*F$4:F$2000, $A$4:$A$2000>=0, isnumber(F$4:F$2000)))
```

and fill to the right for the other columns.
See if that works?